# Encoding format (tmp) is not supported

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, image-uploading

I get an exception when returning `$request` from my controller.

The form in `creat.blade.php`:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.category.store') }}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name">
      <label class="form-label">Category Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="image">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

CategoryController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request;
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning the request object in the first place? What result are you expecting from the above code?

Comment: You should also include the complete error message in your question.